# Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration version 11.0.0.0 doesn't support Document Option anymore?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I upgraded my projects to Visual Studio 2012 and Also use Sql management Studio 2012, however when i did these, and compile my projects it encounter an error like this;

Error   7   The type or namespace name 'DocumentOptions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The dll for "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTools.VSIntegration" is already 11.0.0.0, however when i tried to use version 10.0.0.0, the error was gone.

Document option not supported anymore in version 11.0.0.0 ???

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that underlying .Net etc code has changed a bit and is either no longer (in which case it's been deprecated and it's functionality most likely replaced by another method) in use or has moved... if it has moved do the following...

Search your code for DocumentOptions, go to it, right click any methods the namespace is using and select the resolve reference option... this should update your referencing for that particular issue. Now do the same for the others.

Comment: it doens't work, it doesn't gave any valuable replacement for the missing option.